# Is the difference of an open and a closed set open?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that the set $A$ is open and the set $B$ is closed. Then $A \setminus B$ is open.

I can show this for two cases:

- If $A \cap B=\emptyset$, then $A \setminus B=A$, which is obviously open.
- If $A \subseteq B$, $A \setminus B=\emptyset$, which is open by definition

How do I show this for the general case, ie where $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ and $A \not\subseteq B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A\setminus B=A\cap(X\setminus B)$, where $X$ is the whole space, and since $A$ and $X\setminus B$ are open, $A\setminus B$ is open.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$A\setminus B=A\cap B^c$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $B$ is closed, then its complement $B^c$ is open. $A \setminus B = A \cap B^c$.